# HSK5 level novel to help prepare

Tags: books, hsk

Just got HSK4, and so the real work begins...

Looking for novels to read whose level would be appropriate, any recommendations?

Also looking for TV shows recommendation. I just finished watching 都挺好 and loved it, so something more like that than prince and princess type shows

Cheers

Comment: I read Roald Dahl's books translated into Chinese (玛蒂尔达 and 女巫).  Other options are [web novels](https://novel.zhwenpg.com/); [Chinese 语文](https://www.hackingchinese.com/866-digital-textbooks-for-expanding-your-chinese/); [student written essays](http://www.ruiwen.com/zuowen/wunianjizuowen/); or [see this Reddit list of novels](https://www.reddit.com/r/chinesebookclub/comments/5pb4yx/corpus_of_chinese_novels_sorted_by_difficulty/).

Comment: When asking questions, show your effort first. Did you try to find any HSK5-level reading on your own?

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Thanks for the reccos. I keep seeing 余华 in every list that I'm recommended so I think I'll start with his novels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something by 余华。 For example 现实一种 or 活着。 余华 tends to repeat himself often as a literary device which I found useful when I was preparing for the HSK 6 (I think the level is close enough). However, be warned that his books are pretty dark in tone. He also has some short stories that won't take as much time to read.

Comment: These particular books are available here: [现实一种](https://blah.me/book/1829) and [活着](https://blah.me/book/1824).